# Custom meta POST request fired twice when updating a post in Gutenberg

Tags: custom-field, rest-api, post-meta, block-editor

I have made a feature similar in behaviour to [Revision Notes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/revision-notes/), but for Gutenberg. It is a Gutenberg sidebar plugin which adds a text field where users can write an edit summary when they edit a post, which is then stored as post meta data when the post is saved.

I am new to React but using [this tutorial](https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/make-plugin-compatible-with-gutenberg-sidebar-api/) as a basis I put together this code to make a request to a REST endpoint I defined in my plugin when the post is saved with the contents of the edit summary text box:

```
var el = wp.element.createElement;
var __ = wp.i18n.__;
var Component = wp.element.Component;
var PluginPostStatusInfo = wp.editPost.PluginPostStatusInfo;
var TextControl = wp.components.TextControl;
var registerPlugin = wp.plugins.registerPlugin;
var withSelect = wp.data.withSelect;

class My_Edit_Summary_Plugin extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super( ...arguments );

        this.state = {
            key: 'my_edit_summary',
            // edit summary always initially empty
            value: ''
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update post meta using REST API.
     */
    static getDerivedStateFromProps( nextProps, state ) {
        if ( nextProps.isSaving && !nextProps.isAutoSaving && !nextProps.isPublishing ) {
            if ( nextProps.revisionId ) {
                wp.apiRequest( { path: `/my-plugin/v1/update-meta?id=${nextProps.revisionId}`, method: 'POST', data: state } ).then(
                    ( data ) => {
                        return data;
                    },
                    ( err ) => {
                        return err;
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return el(
            PluginPostStatusInfo,
            {
                className: 'my-edit-summary-panel'
            },
            el(
                TextControl,
                {
                    name: 'my_revision_post_edit_summary',
                    label: __( 'Edit summary', 'my-plugin' ),
                    help: __( 'Briefly summarise your changes', 'my-plugin' ),
                    value: this.state.value,
                    onChange: ( value ) => {
                        this.setState( {
                            value
                        })
                    }
                }
            )
        );
    }
}

/**
 * Give current post IDs and status flags to My_Edit_Summary_Plugin object.
 */
const HOC = withSelect( ( select, { forceIsSaving } ) => {
    const {
        getCurrentPostId,
        getCurrentPostLastRevisionId,
        isSavingPost,
        isPublishingPost,
        isAutosavingPost
    } = select( 'core/editor' );

    return {
        postId: getCurrentPostId(),
        revisionId: getCurrentPostLastRevisionId(),
        isSaving: forceIsSaving || isSavingPost(),
        isAutoSaving: isAutosavingPost(),
        isPublishing: isPublishingPost()
    };
} )( My_Edit_Summary_Plugin );

registerPlugin( 'my-edit-summary-plugin', {
    render: HOC
} );
```

The higher-order component is needed to grab the revision id (required by my REST endpoint). The `/my-plugin/v1/update-meta` REST endpoint saves the metadata using `update_metadata`, and this part works as expected. **The problem I have is that the AJAX request is made twice.** If I add `console.log(nextProps);` under the line `if ( nextProps.revisionId ) {` above, I see two console messages in quick succession when I click "Update" in the editor:

```
Object { postId: 420, revisionId: 426, isSaving: true, isAutoSaving: false, isPublishing: false }
Object { postId: 420, revisionId: 427, isSaving: true, isAutoSaving: false, isPublishing: false }
```

This has the effect that the previous version of the post (`revisionId` == `426`) has its metadata updated as well as the new version. I only want to set the meta data of the new version (i.e. `revisionId` == `427`).

I'd like to know if anyone can see what the problem is, but also whether anyone can think of a better way to save the meta data. It seems like this code is much more complicated than it should be, just to save a single text field. I have seen some mention of `withDispatch` to handle post updates. Perhaps this might be a better way to approach this?

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` isn't a WP API, it gets called by React just before rendering occurs, so using it to "save" stuff via an AJAX request isn't going to be reliable

Comment: As an aside, what does your endpoint do? Could the components not use the GB data stores and have the data sent in the save payloads with everything else?

Comment: See here https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/7535

Comment: Or here: https://github.com/generoi/wp-gutenberg-hidetitle/blob/master/src/component.js You don't need to add a new REST endpoint and call it yourself in order to save post meta values in Gutenberg, and you definitely shouldn't be abusing React render helper methods to do it

Comment: @TomJNowell: the endpoint sets metadata on the new revision (not the parent post). I can't just rely on Gutenberg's data store to set the metadata because it only sets it on the parent. That's why the higher-order component extracts the revision ID and updates that via REST.

Comment: @TomJNowell: Update: I figured it was simpler to do this in PHP. The complicating factor here is that the revision is saved before the metadata is updated (this is a [behaviour only in Gutenberg](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/8032), not with the classic editor). I got it to work though, hooking into `updated_postmeta` to copy the meta value from the parent into the latest revision. Thanks for your help!